# ows_editior missing in Metadata Property Mappings in SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, web-crawler

I'm trying to map a Managed Property to the Modified By field in document library's. I can see that the internal name of the field is Editor. But I can't find ows_editor in crawled Properties.

Is there a way of adding it to the crawled properties, and how?

Answer (score 1):

Upload any document to the library where the mapping column exist.
Then perform a full crawl and you will be able to see the required crawled properties.

Comment: We tried that as it worked with other fields. But ows_editor did not appear.